# How to update a row in a table that has a primary key?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

Trying to update a table which has a primary key (named `Id`) but it won't allow me to update it. This is the error I get:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure update_employee_details, Line 53
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__DB_Actio__3214EC07BDE689AD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DB_Actions'. The duplicate key value is (8).

Code:

```
UPDATE Employee_Details
SET Emp_First_Name = 'John', Emp_Middle_Name = 'Michael'
WHERE Emp_First_Name = 'A';
```

How can I update a record with a table that has a primary key? Seems strange since you would think this would need to be done all of the time.

Thank you.

Comment: The error says, you are trying to insert a duplicate value for primary key. Primary keys should be unique.

Comment: The error message suggests you're trying to insert a row. Your code says you're trying to update a row. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

i think u should change

`UPDATE Employee_Details
SET Emp_First_Name = 'John', Emp_Middle_Name = 'Michael'
WHERE Emp_First_Name = 'A';`

to

`UPDATE Employee_Details
SET Emp_First_Name = 'John', Emp_Middle_Name = 'Michael'
WHERE Emp_ID = '(employee_id)';`